# Using Library In QTCreator Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am building my own library of functions I use to help me learn C++.
I am attempting a simple QT application and when I run the app I get an undefined error.
Not sure what I am doing wrong, and its probably a noob thing.

Library Files

CC_Number.h

```
#ifndef CC_NUMBER_H
#define CC_NUMBER_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CC_Number
{
public:
    CC_Number();
    virtual ~CC_Number();
    int randCC(int imin=0, int imax=1);
    int arraySize(int x[]);
    int arraySize(double x[]);
    int arraySize(float x[]);
    int arraySize(string x[]);
    string int_to_str(int i);
protected:
private:
};
#endif // CC_NUMBER_H
```

CC_Number.cpp

```
#include "CC_Number.h"
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

CC_Number::CC_Number()
{
//ctor
}

CC_Number::~CC_Number()
{
//dtor
}

string CC_Number::int_to_str(int i){
stringstream ss;
ss << i;
string str = ss.str();
return str;
}
```

Code That Calls The Library

Animal_Birthdate.h

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_BIRTHDATE_H
#define ANIMAL_BIRTHDATE_H
#include "/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_Number.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Animal_Birthdate
{
public:
Animal_Birthdate();
Animal_Birthdate(int m, int d, int y);
string getBirthdate();
private:
int intMonth;
int intDay;
int intYear;
};

#endif // ANIMAL_BIRTHDATE_H
```

Animal_Birthdate.cpp

```
#include "animal_birthdate.h"
#include "/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_Number.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Animal_Birthdate::Animal_Birthdate()
:intMonth(1), intDay(1), intYear(1)
{

}

Animal_Birthdate::Animal_Birthdate(int m, int d, int y)
:intMonth(m), intDay(d), intYear(y)
{

}

string Animal_Birthdate::getBirthdate()
{
CC_Number c;
string bd = c.int_to_str(intMonth);
return bd;
}
```

Errors I am Receiving
/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Herd_Manager/animal_birthdate.o:-1: In function `Animal_Birthdate::getBirthdate()':

/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Herd_Manager/animal_birthdate.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `CC_Number::CC_Number()'

/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Herd_Manager/animal_birthdate.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `CC_Number::int_to_str(int)'

Contents of CC_Cpp.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-05-31T10:42:21
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       -= core gui

TARGET = CC_Cpp
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += CC_CPP_LIBRARY

SOURCES += \
CC_Number.cpp \
CC_File.cpp

HEADERS +=\
    cc_cpp_global.h \
CC_Number.h \
CC_File.h

unix:!symbian {
maemo5 {
    target.path = /opt/usr/lib
} else {
    target.path = /usr/lib
}
INSTALLS += target
}
```

Comment: how do you compile it?
Can you show the Makefile?

Comment: I'm on a linux machine, not sure where to find this

Would it be something like this?
qmake-qt4 /home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_Cpp.pro -r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug

Comment: And what is the content of CC_Cpp.pro ?

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to the template file of the project that was trying to use the library and it worked.

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
animal.cpp \
email.cpp \
owner.cpp \
phone.cpp \
/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_Number.cpp \
/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_Date.cpp \
/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_TimeStamp.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
animal.h \
email.h \
owner.h \
phone.h \
/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_Number.h \
/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_Date.h \
/home/mongo/Cpp/CC_Cpp/CC_TimeStamp.h
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look that you need "a library" for what you're doing. I'd suggest simply using multiple translation units linked together into a simple application as a starting point. I.e. remove `TEMPLATE = lib` and you'll be set.

If you'd like to learn how to create libraries with `qmake`, read about the `TEMPLATE = subdirs` and read qmake's documentation which contains all information about how to produce libraries, what the difference between static and dynamic ones are, how to link to them, etc.

Comment: That worked...sorta. It allowed me to find some errors in my code, but now I am getting        /usr/lib/crt1.o:-1: In function `_start':         (.text+0x18):-1: error: undefined reference to `main'

Comment: I replaced the TEMPLATE = lib in the .pro file and I can compile it completely now however when I try compiling the main program I still get the undefined error could it be the way I am linking the .h file?

Comment: That's because you do not have a ``main`` function.

Comment: I added a main function and set the template to TEMPLATE = app however I still get an undefined reference to the classes I am trying to use.